# Cookie authentication when reguistering users through REST API

Tags: commerce, authentication-authorization, cookies

I am running Drupal 9 commerce 2.0 as headless CMS, and I am trying to integrate the user registration/user login part of my frontend application. I was able to use the user/register REST API to create users. The default (only option without other modules) authentication was cookie authentication. What I am trying to understand is how the cookie authentication works. When running `curl -d @data.json http://example.com/user/register?_format=hal_json --header "Content-Type:application/hal+json"` for example, everything works perfectly fine, and the user is created. But don't I need to add a Set-Cookie header for this to work since the REST API has cookie authentication checked? How does this cookie authentication work?

Comment: This site is set up to answer one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Comment: The cookie header should be in the response, correct? Is this just registering, or are you authenticating that new user somewhere?

Comment: Set-Cookie is a response header not a request header.

Comment: Right, the client would then have it. With Curl, there is additional handling needed - see https://www.drupal.org/node/1795770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a login using the login endpoint you'll get a cookie back (as well as a CSRF token) which you can then use for subsequent requests instead of doing a fresh login every time.

So with curl something like this:

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" 
  --request POST \
  -s -c cookie.txt \
  --data-binary '{"name": "user1", "pass": "pass1"}' \
  https://.../user/login
```

Would get you back a cookie in cookie.txt and the json response will contain your CSRF token.